# How to release/deallocate/return-from a viewcontroller class that have been popped?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I have a UINavigationController in my application where I am pushing a view controller. On that viewcontroller, there is a preloader view that shows animation while the data is being downloaded and parsed in the background. Below the animation is a button that should redirect the user to some other view controller.

Now, I can accomplish this by popping the viewcontroller since the view I need to be directed to is the view the current view was pushed from. The problem here, however, is that the downloading, parsing, timer, etc.. everything keeps happening in the background.

The functionality I need is for the viewcontroller to completely stop working as soon as I pop the VC by clicking on the button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to run the background operations?

You can simplify background operations by subclassing NSOperation and using NSOperationQueue to run it. You just have to release NSOperationQueue and iOS will clean up for you automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Here is an example.

```
@interface MyBackgroundOperation : NSOperation
@end

@implementation MyBackgroundOperation
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil)
    {        
        // stuff that needs to be done at init
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)main
{
    @try
    {
        // run my background operations
    }
    @catch (NSException *e)
    {
        // catch the exception
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // clean up
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Then you start the operation like this

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

MyBackgroundOperation *myOperation = [[MyBackgroundOperation alloc] init];
[operationQueue addOperation:myOperation];
[myOperation release];

[operationQueue release];
```

The OS will retain the operation until it's finished so that releasing the view controller will not effect it. However, if you want to stop the operation after it's already started you're going to have to use a bit more fancy techniques, maybe notifications or KVO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I seem to have left a few details. I am loading the view I am talking about with a full screen activity indicator view. The view gets hidden as soon as the parsing and downloading is done. By background, it isn't actually doing stuff in the background thread. Now, when I exit the class mid-processing (downloading and parsing) the parsing, and all the other operations must stop. Basically the class should get off the application like it was never called. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you must run the operation in the main thread? It depends on what your code looks like but I recommend doing your downloads and parsing in a background thread and updating the main view using performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone. That way the app will be more responsive and you won't have to worry about the app crashing because you released something.

Comment: I know, and thanks for the tip. Let's assume I have put all the processing to the background thread but that doesn't solve my problem yet. The code still keeps running in the background even though I have moved away from the class. I want to unload that class and put everything that's happening in that class to rest.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my comment, you could send a notification to the background thread so that it knows when to stop and clean up.